# Call another method inside the method in Java

Tags: java, methods

I'm doing an exercise about the method and one-dimensional arrays. I created an array under a method. How can I use that array under another method? For example, I determined a few identities in my first method and the second, I will extract some features from those identities using these identities. Let's say that the more times "xyz" are written in this code, I will increase their health by 1.

Comment: I don't see where you "created an array."  Can you elaborate what you are trying to do here?  The only array I see is `IDs` and that appears to be already created.

Comment: `IDs` is not declared anywhere inside your method, so you can access it from another method in the same class the same way you're accessing it in `calculateHealth`.

Comment: OK so this code does not compile.  When you have a problem like that, we need the *full text* of the error message too.  There's a post somewhere on SO "Why 'Can someone help me?' is not a question."  That's this question.

Comment: Change `population` to return `String[]` instead of returning `void`, and call it from `calculateHealth` like `String[] IDs = population(health);` Then you will have the array that was created by one method in the other method.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the Array ID's is currently a local variable of your method *population*

Here some important Points about Variable in scope in Java:

- In general, a set of curly brackets { } defines a scope.
- Any variable defined in a class outside of any method can be used by all member methods.
- In Java we can usually access a variable as long as it was defined within the same set of brackets as the code we are writing or within any curly brackets inside of the curly brackets where the variable was defined.

Scope means that variables are only accessible inside the region they are created.

Here an example to show this behavior

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Code here CANNOT use x

    { // This is a block

      // Code here CANNOT use x

      int x = 100;

      // Code here CAN use x
      System.out.println(x);

   } // The block ends here

  // Code here CANNOT use x

  }
}
```

In your case you can define the id's in a "higher scope" outside of your population method.

```
public class L {
    public static String[] IDs = new String[n];

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            
        
}
        public static void population(int n){
            String[] letter = {"x","y","z"};
            for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
                IDs[j] = "";
                for (int i=0; i<128; i++){
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    int w = rand.nextInt(letter.length);
                    IDs[j]+=letter[w];
                }
            }
        }

         private static void calculateHealth(int health) {
            population(health);
            health =0;

            for (int i=2; i<128; i++){
                if (IDs[i-2].equals("X") && IDs[i-1].equals("Y") && IDs[i].equals("Z")) {
                    health+=1;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(health);;
        }
}
```

Then you can use it in both of your methods.

---

Here is another solution for this problem where you don't have to care about scopes. You can just pass to each of the functions an array as parameter.

```
public class L {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            
        
}
        public static void population(String[] IDs, int n){
            String[] letter = {"x","y","z"};
            for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
                IDs[j] = "";
                for (int i=0; i<128; i++){
                    Random rand = new Random();
                    int w = rand.nextInt(letter.length);
                    IDs[j]+=letter[w];
                }
            }
        }

         private static void calculateHealth(String[] IDs, int health) {
            population(health);
            health =0;

            for (int i=2; i<128; i++){
                if (IDs[i-2].equals("X") && IDs[i-1].equals("Y") && IDs[i].equals("Z")) {
                    health+=1;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(health);;
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure telling newbies to increase the scope of the variable rather than telling them how to pass it as a parameter is such a good thing, although obviously you can solve this issue either way.

Comment: @DavidConrad well passing as parameter is also a good choice. But I don't think that it makes so much difference which way you choose here and by the way getting in touch which scopes is not bad because it is important to understand and knowledge what is also transferable to other programming languages

Comment: It's certainly important to understand scopes. It's also a good habit to write referentially transparent code that doesn't depend on state that wasn't passed in, and to keep scopes limited to only what they need to be.

Comment: @DavidConrad that's true. I have added it to my solution, ty for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare the `String[]` outside of the method declaration; setting it's dimension is useless:

```
String[] IDs = new String[]{};
```

And you probably don't need these `static` keywords either.

Comment: It would be much better to pass it as a parameter to the other method.

Answer (score 0):

well there are two things
1st - As alex mentioned
2nd you can create array in that function

```
public static String[] population(int n){
    String[] IDs = new String[n];
    String[] letter = {"x","y","z"};
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
        IDs[j] = "";
        for (int i=0; i<128; i++){
            Random rand = new Random();
            int w = rand.nextInt(letter.length);
            IDs[j]+=letter[w];
        }
    }
    return IDs;
}

 private static void calculateHealth(int health) {
    String[] Ids = population(health);
    health =0;

    for (int i=2; i<128; i++){
        if (IDs[i-2].equals("X") && IDs[i-1].equals("Y") && IDs[i].equals("Z")) {
            health+=1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(health);;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this is a good idea. When you would like to make changes on that array than you have to do this changes on both. This is an entry for mistakes and bugs. 
When you uses it with parameters you can pass to both functions the same array or when you use it as "global variable" then you have it on one point and make your changes there

Comment: Yes Alex totally agree. Just giving another possibility  over here